# Reply to a message discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I want to make my bot react to a users message when they type a certain sentence.

My code to reply:

```
await ctx.message.reply("I just replied to you")
```

I get the error:

```
ctx.message has no attribute "reply"
```

What code can I do to make the bot reply to the message?

When I say reply, I mean the same as a user can press reply on a message

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To any new user here, as of the **1.6.0 discord.py-rewrite** update, you are now able to reply!

Every message or context now has a reply attribute. To reply, simply use

```py
await ctx.reply('Hello!')
```

You can also not mention the author in the reply with `mention_author=False`

```py
await ctx.reply('Hello!', mention_author=False)
```

[image: No reply example]
[image: Reply example]

You can also find a basic example [Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/reply.py)

Comment: I got an error saying that `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'reply'`, can someone help?

Comment: @NicholasChen You need to update to discord.py 1.6

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that

Answer (score 4):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hi":
        await message.channel.send("hello", reference=message)
```

The main thing here is `reference=message`. It is available since Discord.py 1.6.

More info: [1](https://www.tutorialguruji.com/python/discord-py-how-to-get-the-last-message-and-reply-to-it-without-any-prefix-command/), [2](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20send#discord.TextChannel.send).

Answer (score -1):

one option is to use a `Cog.listener` you can find [documentation on Cog.listener here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog%20listen#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener), but to answer your question, the way I did my Cog.listener was:

```
@bot.listen('on_message') 
async def stuff(message):

    if message.content.startswith("buttlerprefix"): # this tells the bot what to listen for. If a user types `buttlerprefix` in any text channel, it will respond with what's below
        msg = await message.channel.send("my prefix is `>`") # set the sending message equal to a variable so that you can manipulate it later like I did with the timer, and delete function below
        await asyncio.sleep(10) # tells the bot to wait 10 seconds before continuing below
        await msg.delete() # deletes the send message after 10 seconds
```

if you have any further questions, or you encounter any errors that I don't see here, then please follow up with me :)

Comment: Hi, when i say "reply" i mean reply as in a user would right click and press reply

Comment: ah I got you. I do apologize, but I'm not sure how one would go about doing that :( I will be following this though so that if someone has figured out a way, then I can learn something new too :)

Answer (score -1):

Discord.py does not have support for the new "reply" feature yet. Unfortunately, you can't really use the reply feature unless they added it to the libary.

Comment: This is outdated.

Answer (score -4):

Try replacing the line with

```
await ctx.send('I just replied to you')
```

Comment: No i know that to send a message you can use that, but i want it to specifically reply to the message, like when you right click on a message and press reply

Comment: What version of discord.py do you use? The documentation says that it was added in version 1.6.

Comment: I don't know if this has to do with me using PyCharm but according to it, the latest version of discord.py is 1.5.1, so maybe it's something that hasn't been implemented yet.